# High load but nothing shows up on system monitor, what could be the cause?

Tags: 15.04, 14.10

I am seeing all CPUs running at about 50% and the load indicator constantly says I have a high load running on the PC. However the process lists only shows a handful things running at lowish CPU each (7, 7, 3, 2, 1, 1, 1).

What could be causing high load and yet not showing up on the system monitor?

Likewise it says that I am using 10G of memory but aside for Open Office sitting on 3.8G and Java on 0.5G I cannot account for the memory use.

**UPDATE:** Restarting does not help.

[image: Screenshot]
<sup>**This is my system prior to restarting with every program I was using closed.**  (Click images to enlarge)</sup>

[image: Screenshot]
<sup>**This is the process list. Nothing seems to account for the high CPU.**</sup>

**UPDATE:** Updated to 15.04 - system monitor shows 2% CPU use, load indicator says 1.27 (out of 2).

Comment: I have since moved to 15.04 and am seeing the same problem.

Comment: 3.8GB memory usage for OpenOffice is very high. I sometimes do complicated tasks with LibreOffice without using anywhere close to that amount of memory. I also have Microsoft Office 2007, but I don't use it because LibreOffice is so much faster than MS Office. I used to use OpenOffice when Ubuntu shipped with it, but my OpenOffice did not use that much memory either.

Answer (score 1):

First, you should make sure you understand what load measures. I'm not sure what you are considering high load. If you have a dual core system, a load of 2.0 would mean that your system is constantly busy. If you have a single core system, then a load of 2.0 would be really bad. See http://blog.scoutapp.com/articles/2009/07/31/understanding-load-averages.

On the processes page, what do you have selected on the View dropdown menu button? You probably want to make sure you have "All Processes" selected. If you don't, things started by other users (likely root) like Xorg (which will use some memory) will not show up.

Comment: You can see the other processes like ones owned by root etc which is why it is so busy. Also the CPUs are both pushing 30% (after all user apps closed, except I think dropbox which I might have forgotten about) but the apps list 19% total CPU.

Answer (score 0):

Well from your images it seems as tho you have every program under the sun running. Try to stop any programs from running at start or close any unused programs.

Comment: I'm showing all processes. Aside from Apache most of that is background Linux stuff as far as I know.